# Mysql binary searching

Tags: mysql, binary, bit-manipulation

#### Situation

I want to convert certain status fields within my PHP/MySQL application to handle more than one at any time. Take below what is currently an ENUM field as an example:

```
STATUS_ACTIVE
STATUS_FROZEN
STATUS_PENDING
STATUS_FLAGGED
STATUS_DELETED
```

Currently, it will only support one at a time. However by converting the set in to binary, I end up up with a set of strings.

```
1     STATUS_ACTIVE
10    STATUS_FROZEN
100   STATUS_PENDING
1000  STATUS_FLAGGED
10000 STATUS_DELETED
```

Now, when it comes to filtering PHP wise, I have no issues. However, this introduces a large (and unnecessary) overhead. It is very possible an entry could end up as

```
10010
01110
etc.
```

#### Question

I've done some digging around and the best piece of information I have found was actually on stackoverflow (ironically) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801352/storing-binary-string-in-mysql). <strike>Can someone please explain the actual syntax used there or point me to a correct MySQL manual page.</strike>

It's not very clear just how one would hypothetically go about these situations:

```
Changing only the third bit
Searching for 1 on only the fourth bit
Updating two binary flags at the same time
```

It would be really appreciated to have even a knock in the right direction, thanks for reading.

Edit: I have figured out most of the syntax. My question now: is it possible to change more than one bit at a time without having to redefine the whole thing?

```
I.e

100 -> 1011
1 -> 101
```

Comment: Experimentation is the mother of all learning. I created a test database to play around with and got shuffling. I'm still a little curious whether or not two bits can be changed in the same query though. Updating the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your updated question. For example we need 3 and 5 bits.

If you need to SET 3 and 5 bits you should `OR` your field with `10100`

```
UPDATE table SET options = options | ((1 << 2) | (1 << 4))
```

If you need to CLEAR 3 and 5 bits you should `AND` your field with `11101011 = NOT(10100)`

```
UPDATE table SET options = options & (~((1 << 2) | (1 << 4)))
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, thank you kindly for responding :)